# Find Mean in Each Group

Tags: r, dataframe, data-processing

Within each group, I want to find the mean for two sub-groups. To be clear, the data looks like the following:

```
Group Val1 Val2 Val3
1     50   0.03  50.1
1     50.2 0.05  50.1
2     50.3 0.01  50.1
1     50   0.03  50.2
1     50.1 0.04  50.2
1     50   0.01  50.3
1     50   0.02  50.3
2     50.3 0.03  50.3
```

Within each group in Val3, I want to calculate the mean of Val2 in Group 1 and the mean of Val2 in Group 2. In some cases, for Val3, there are no members in Group 2. This is the code I attempted.

```
fileB.mean.dat <- tapply(combined.sorted.data[combined.sorted.data[,1] == 2,3], combined.sorted.data[combined.sorted.data[,1] == 2,4], mean)
```

I don't know how to include in the code above to check for whether there are members of group 2 and if not to make the mean 0 for Val 3. In other words, there should be a representative mean value for Group 1 and 2 for every value of Val 3.

Comment: `aggregate(Val2 ~ Group + Val3, data = df, mean)` will give the mean per group. But won't give you the 'missing' mean (and I'm not entirely sure the benefit of having a mean for data that doesn't exist?)

Comment: I want to plot the data. Therefore, I want to have the mean to show in the plot (even if the mean is 0 for missing data).

Comment: having a mean of zero for missing data is still quite misleading.

Comment: You could use `tidyr::complete` to insert the missing combination, e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% complete(Group, Val3) %>% group_by(Group, Val3) %>% summarise_all(mean)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dcast` of `reshape2` to convert output of [SymbolixAU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949511/find-mean-in-each-group#comment78857815_45949511) to your liking.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data = aggregate(Val2 ~ Group + Val3, data = df, mean),
      formula = Group~Val3,
      value.var = "Val2")
#  Group 50.1  50.2  50.3
#1     1 0.04 0.035 0.015
#2     2 0.01    NA 0.030
```

Or you could do it in base R too but would be relatively more complex

```
sapply(split(df[c("Group", "Val2")], df$Val3),
       function(a) sapply(unique(df$Group),
            function(x) setNames(mean(a$Val2[a$Group == x]), x)))
#  50.1  50.2  50.3
#1 0.04 0.035 0.015
#2 0.01   NaN 0.030
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5), Val1 = c(50, 
50.2, 50.3, 50, 50.1, 50, 50, 50.3), Val2 = c(0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 
0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03), Val3 = c(50.1, 50.1, 50.1, 50.2, 
50.2, 50.3, 50.3, 50.3)), .Names = c("Group", "Val1", "Val2", 
"Val3"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(Group, Val3) %>%
   summarise(Val2 = mean(Val2)) %>% 
   spread(Val3, Val2)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Group [2]
#   Group `50.1` `50.2` `50.3`
#* <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1   0.04  0.035  0.015
#2     2   0.01     NA  0.030
```

Comment: This gives the following error: "Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'Val3' not found". Do you know why?

Comment: @user2657817  I tried it again and couldn't find any error.  Could you check the column names? There could be some trailing whitespaces.  I used `dplyr_0.7.4`